# **Index was outisde the bounds of array** with SVD computation using Meta.Numeric.Matrices

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, svd

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing  ;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using Meta.Numerics.Matrices;  

 double[,] ptsImgOne = new double[3, 5];  
 double[,] ptsImgTwo = new double[3, 5];  


 ptsImgOne = new double[,] { { 0.41726, 0.94478, 0.33771, 0.11120, 0.24169 }, 
{ 0.04965, 0.49086, 0.90005, 0.78025, 0.40391}, 
{ 0.90271, 0.48925, 0.36924, 0.38973, 0.09645 } };  
ptsImgTwo = new double[,] { { 0.13197, 0.57520, 0.35315, 0.04302, 0.73172 },
 { 0.94205, 0.05977, 0.82119, 0.16899, 0.64774 },
 { 0.95613, 0.23477, 0.01540, 0.64911, 0.45092 } };


            RectangularMatrix q1 = new RectangularMatrix(ptsImgOne);
            RectangularMatrix q2 = new RectangularMatrix(ptsImgTwo);


            RectangularMatrix Qmultiply = new RectangularMatrix(5, 9);
            for (int i = 0; i < q2.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                Qmultiply[i, 0] = q1[0, i] * q2[0, i]; 
                Qmultiply[i, 1] = q1[1, i] * q2[0, i]; 
                Qmultiply[i, 2] = q1[2, i] * q2[0, i]; 

                Qmultiply[i, 3] = q1[0, i] * q2[1, i];
                Qmultiply[i, 4] = q1[1, i] * q2[1, i];
                Qmultiply[i, 5] = q1[2, i] * q2[1, i];

                Qmultiply[i, 6] = q1[0, i] * q2[2, i];
                Qmultiply[i, 7] = q1[1, i] * q2[2, i];
                Qmultiply[i, 8] = q1[2, i] * q2[2, i]; 
            }


SingularValueDecomposition singValDec=    Qmultiply.SingularValueDecomposition();




        }
    }
}
```

I am using Meta.Numerics.Matrices to work with matrices and calculate SVD,
but whenever the compiler get to to the last line of code:
"SingularValueDecomposition singValDec=Qmultiply.SingularValueDecomposition();"
I get an error saying **Index was outisde the bounds of array**. I double-checked  boundries for the Qmultiply array and the rest.I tried to debug it, but the error persists.
Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **Meta package** has **some bugs** in **calculation of SVD**.

I used **MathNet** with same code and it worked very well.

To be on the safe side, use MathNet(Math.Numeric).